# PHP is not responding when called by ajax for validations

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to validate my signup form using php and ajax. But i am not getting any value in return. This is my ajax code.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function frmValidation(str) 
    {
        if (str=="") 
        {
            document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else 
        {  
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?value="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }  
    }
```

And my php file named as validation.php is

```
<?php
    $value= $_REQUEST["value"];

$pass= $_REQUEST["value"];
$error="";

if($value=="")
{
    echo "This is a mandatory field";
}
elseif($value=="fname")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct First Name";
    }
}

elseif($value=="lname")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct Last Name";
    }
}

elseif($value=="designation")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct designation";
    }
}

elseif($value=="suburb")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct suburb";
    }
}

elseif($value=="city")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct city name";
    }
}

elseif($value=="state")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct state";
    }
}

elseif($value=="country")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct country";
    }
}

elseif($value=="pincode")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct designation";
    }
}

elseif($value=="mobile")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[\+0-9\-\(\)\s]*$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct designation";
    }
}

elseif($value=="email")
{
    if(!preg_match("/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/", $value))
    {
        echo "Please enter the correct email format";
    }
}

elseif($value=="cpass")
{
    if($pass==$value)
    {
        echo "Confirm password is wrong";
    }
}
?>
```

The HTML form is this

```
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Sign Up form</h1>
    <form role="form" action="signup.php" method="post">
    <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"> General Information </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="frmValidation(this.value)" tabindex="1" id="First Name" placeholder="First Name" name="fname"><span id="txtError" style="color: red"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Company Name">Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="3" class="form-control" id="Company Name" placeholder="Company Name" name="cname">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="5" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" name="address">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="7" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City" name="city">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="9" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Country" name="country">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile No.</label>
                <input type="text" tabindex="11" class="form-control" id="suburb" placeholder="Mobile No." name="mobile">
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="2" class="form-control" id="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Designation">Designation</label>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="4" class="form-control" id="Designation" placeholder="Designation" name="designation">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="suburb">Suburb</label>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="6" class="form-control" id="suburb" placeholder="Suburb" name="suburb">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="state">State</label>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="8" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="State" name="state">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pincode">Pincode</label>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="10" class="form-control" id="pincode" placeholder="Pincode" name="pincode">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob">Date Of Birth</label>
                    <input type="text" tabindex="12" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"> Login Details </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" tabindex="13" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" tabindex="14" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Confirm password">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" tabindex="14" class="form-control" id="confirm password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpass">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" tabindex="15" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
</div>
```

In html form i am trying to get value for at least first field just to check for weather it is working or not. But i am getting no value in return. Please let me know where is the problem as i am new to use ajax.
Please help! thank you!

Comment: Please check your browser console while AJAX request, May there is some hint.

Comment: Your `xmlhttp.open()` and `xmlhttp.send();` call is inside your `onreadystatechange` callback... they are supposed to be outside it

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is incorrect, which hides a bug in your code: you tell the computer "when the AJAX *response* is received, then send the AJAX *request*". Of course, unless you send the request *first*, there won't be any response to react to.

This is your code, corrected:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
    {
        document.getElementById("txtError").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    // we're still in the "onreadystatechange" function here!
    // xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?value="+str,true);
    // xmlhttp.send();
}  
// send the request from *here*
xmlhttp.open("GET","validation.php?value="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was having some other problem with the code too. I was sending value of the text input field and in php i was trying to expect the name of the text input field. Now the other prblm is i want the name of the input field. can you please help me in that? How can i send the name of the input field to the php using ajax.

Comment: Other problem - other question ;)

Comment: u can name it anything u liike

Comment: Okay, longer explanation: if you have a *different* problem, post a *new* *question* - asking around in *comments* is not the way we do it here.